# Count e length em Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho um projeto Django e uma das funcionalidades dele é gerar números estatísticos. Por exemplo: tenho um modelo de funcionários e ele tem campos booleanos, tipo, se está ativo ou não, presente ou não, etc. Daí quero mostrar no template um card contendo o total de funcionários cadastrados e quantos desses estão ativo e em determinado dia quantos estavam presentes, etc. Ou seja, a quantidade será mostrada conforme o estado do objeto, se true ou false. Confira um exemplo de modelo:
models.py

```
class Funcionario(models.Model):
    nome = ...
    ativo = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

views.py

```
from .models import Funcionario

class IndexView(TemplateView): # TemplateView mesmo
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['funcionarios'] = Funcionario.objects.all()
        return context
```

Sei que é tranquilo mostrar o total no template usando `{{ funcionarios.count }}` ou `{{ funcionarios|length }}`. Mas ainda não entendi realmente a diferença entre os dois modos. Porém, minha pergunta é sobre como mostrar o número de funcionário ativos e inativos. Alguns alternativas que pensei foi criar várias chaves no `def get_context_data`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['funcionarios'] = Funcionario.objects.all()
    context['funcionarios_ativos'] = Funcionario.objects.filter(ativo=True)
    context['funcionarios_inativos'] = Funcionario.objects.filter(ativo=False)
    ...

    return context
```

Ou poderia criar `@propety` no model `Funcionario`; ou poderia criar tag personalizadas. Enfim, gostaria de uma opinião sobre qual seria a forma mais adequada de se fazer isso.

Comment: Cria um `manager` para o `Funcionario` no seu models. (`FunicionarioManager(models.Manager)`). Dentro dele crie o método que vai contar por `ativo`. Caso tenha dúvida de como fazer, manda mensagem.

Comment: Excelente sugestão, Paulo Marques. Muito obrigado.